# outdated links in tag wiki

Tags: discussion, support, tag-wiki

Was reading 'scala' tag wiki and noticed that some link is outdated, it's not broken, but leads to "Buy this domain" page instead.

What is the procedure in such situation ?
Should I contact tag-wiki creator or there is somebody else who might update it ? Since I do not have enough reputation to do that myself.

thank you.

Edit: link that is broken is in this part of wiki "To search Scala documentation, you can use scalex."

Comment: I fixed the Scalex link. Is that the (only) link you meant? There's a *lot* of them...

Comment: yes, so far that is the only link that I noticed was outdated,
I was just about to edit questions to add the link itself